# git reflog missing data when piping

Tags: bash, git, grep, git-tag

With

```
git reflog
```

output log look like this

```
8b388bc (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{0}: commit (amend): tempppp22222
7c33c70 (tag: v2.0) HEAD@{1}: commit: tempppp
76702b2 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to HEAD^
fc1ea9d HEAD@{3}: commit (amend): temp2
0bc8223 (tag: v1.0) HEAD@{4}: reset: moving to 0bc8223
```

but when I try

```
git reflog | grep "HEAD@{1}"
```

the output look like this

```
7c33c70 HEAD@{1}: commit: tempppp
```

Can someone tell me why the tag name is missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git reflog --help`:

> OPTIONS
> Options for show
> git reflog show accepts any of the options accepted by git log.

`git log --help`:

> OPTIONS
> --no-decorate, --decorate[=short|full|auto|no]
> Print out the ref names of any commits that are shown. If short is specified, the ref name prefixes refs/heads/, refs/tags/ and refs/remotes/ will not be printed. If full is specified, the full ref name (including prefix) will be printed. If auto is specified, then if the output is going to a terminal, the ref names are shown as if short were given, otherwise no ref names are shown. The option --decorate is short-hand for --decorate=short. Default to configuration value of log.decorate if configured, otherwise, auto.

**TL;DR:** use `--decorate`

Comment: git reflog --decorate=short | grep "HEAD@{1}" solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: _"The default option is short."_ -- seems to me the default is **auto**.

Comment: @user9645, updated (I think the docs were previously confusing, where not setting `--decorate` would use `auto`, but setting `--decorate` without an argument would use `short`).